# Setting variable value using two macros in C++

Tags: c++, macros

I have a code block like this:

```
#ifdef AB
    int value = 5;
#else
    int value = 10;
#endif

#ifdef CD
    int value = 9;
#else
    int value = 11;
#endif
```

But now my problem is, if both AB and CD macros are active, the value is set to 9. I have two projects in same solution. One uses AB and another CD, so how can I differentiate without putting them in separate solutions?

Comment: `int value 11;`, you mean `int value = 11;`?

Comment: I guess those else-s are in fact #else ...

Comment: I get error: redefinition of 'int value' when i try to run this code with both macros defined, and with the else-s changed to #else-s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a macro for this.

It should be obvious that if you need both variables to exist at the same time, with both values, then they cannot have the same name. Consider an array or container of some kind, which can contain both values, indexed with a convenient descriptive name.

Or simply have two differently-named variables, and decide which one to *use* at any given point based on whatever condition is appropriate.

Comment: @snowden: You're welcome, Edward.